# Hiding toolbar on long press

Tags: android, android-toolbar, show-hide

I want to hide the toolbar on long press in the adapter class. but whatever way I choose it keeps giving me error that the  Attempt to invoke virtual method `'void androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference` or something like that. Here is my method

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar;

  public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main,parent,false);
      public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int  position) {

        holder.item.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
               MenuItem menuItem  = mode.getMenu().findItem(R.id.my_toolbar);
               menuItem.setVisible(false); or
               toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
               toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and this is the xml file of the fragment activity in which the toolbar exists.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".FragmentOne">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

         <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:listitem="@layout/main"
             android:id="@+id/RV"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What do `mode` and `view` represent?

Comment: onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) in long click method and view is created in onCreateViewHolder in adapter class.

Comment: Is there a Toolbar in each row of the adapter?

Comment: I just initialize it in the long click listener as shown above but there is a toolbar in another fragment with the same id so I changed them but the result is same

Comment: There isn't actually a declaration for `view` specifically in your code sample? The only line referencing it is `view.findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);`.

Comment: I have added the view reference above in onCreateViewHolder. I think the reason could be that in view reference main.xml is inflated in which toolbar does not exist as it exists in fragmentOne.xml which is shown above.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues here, based on your comments is seems like the `view` variable is getting reassigned for every row on `onCreateViewHolder`, so when it comes to `onBindViewHolder` you have no guarantee that the current reference is related to the view you're binding. Instead you should be retrieving the bound view from the view holder, something like:

```
holder.itemView
```

Regardless, you're expecting to find the `Toolbar`, which resides in the same fragment as your `RecyclerView`, by calling `findViewById` on a child of your `RecyclerView`. If you have a look at the documentation or source code for `findViewById` you can see that it traverses the view hierarchy downwards, looking at child views for a match, so it will never reach your `Toolbar`.

---

A dirty solution would be to pass in a reference to the `Toolbar` when setting up your `RecyclerView` but the recommended approach would be to pass in a callback to the adapter, which can be set by the fragment and called when long clicking your `itemView`.

Comment: view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_One, container, false);
this view is in onCreateView of FragmentOne class which contains the fragment_One.xml that has that toolbar. Based on your answer I think I need this view. but how can I use that view in adapter class?

Comment: If you read the recommendation in my answer, I would pass in a callback to your adapter, not the view